# How to implement trust/remember device in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I need to implement trust/remember device when login into a Angular.js website. That is I can choose to not have to enter password and username on the computer and device I use every day but if some person gets my password and tries to login on some unknown computer or device, they will still have to enter the password and username to login.

Comment: This is an experimental technology, but follow the concept that your comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API

Answer (score 0):

There is something called document.cookie that you could use in a factory. I found some example code that you might be able to use?

Creates a cookie (for example this one expires in a year):

```
app.factory('$remember', function() {
  return function(name, values) {
    var cookie = name + '=';

    cookie += values + ';';

      var date = new Date();
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365);

      cookie += 'expires=' + date.toString() + ';';

      document.cookie = cookie;
    }
});
```

This factory removes the cookie:

```
app.factory('$forget', function() {
  return function(name) {
    var cookie = name + '=;';
    cookie += 'expires=' + (new Date()).toString() + ';';

    document.cookie = cookie;
  }
});
```

Then whenever a user successfully logs in cache the key using $remember

```
$remember('my_cookie_name', response.user._id);
```

And always check if the cookie is there when logging in the user else use a a standard login and save it to their cookies. If the remember me is not enabled, forget the document.cookie

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If someone guesses the user._jd and sets the cookie through browser console, then he could login to the website, right? How to prevent such situation? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. Were you asking how to set the "remember me" to have your username and pasword set, or auth for logging in? I usually use a JWT in node and have every single endpoint(except for the initial login endpoint that checks username and password) run a function called "ensureAuthenticated" before being hit that checks the validity of a token. If the token is still valid, then it runs next(), and hits the endpoint. If the token isnt valid, or there is no token, it takes them to the login screen. And no problem! I hope I can help haha

Comment: Also, when they log in, it either updates or creates a new JWT. My "ensureAuthenticated" function also updates the token to last longer so it wont run out while they're using the site. And since I run that function on every endpoint, the token is constantly getting renewed while using. If you want some examples of my JWT function, let me know 